# sed command to swap elements in a line

Tags: sed

I'm trying to swap a few elements in the apache dir.conf file which looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_dir.c>
        DirectoryIndex index.html index.cgi index.pl index.php index.xhtml index.htm
</IfModule>
```

I want to swap, `index.html` for `index.php`, this is the desired output:

```
<IfModule mod_dir.c>
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.cgi index.pl index.xhtml index.htm
</IfModule>
```

This is the command I have so far, but I am sure there is a much cleaner way to write it:

```
sed -e '2s/\(.*\)\s\(.*\)\s\(.*\)\s\(.*\)\s\(.*\)\s\(.*\)\s\(.*\)\s\(.*\)/\1 \2 \6 \3 \4 \5 \7 \8/'
```

btw I left the '2s...' since I only want to modify the second row of the file.

Answer (score 1):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -pe 's/index\.(?:(php)|(html))/$1 ? "index.html" : "index.php"/ge if 2 == $.'
```

The `/e` makes the replacement part of the `s///` operator act like code, so `$1` is tested for truthfulness, and if it's true, then there was `php`, so we replace it with `html`, otherwise, there was `html`, so we replace it with `php`.